# Error during karma testing

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

Whenever I try to run the Karma test using Grunt it shows me the following lines.

```
Chromium 31.0.1650 (Ubuntu) is idle
```

What should be the possible reason for this and how can we overcome this error.Thank you..

Comment: Is chromium active? I.e. is it opened and not on the background

Comment: @TimCastelijns yeah ! the chromium browser is active and i am browsing using the chromium browser. But still i don't know why i am getting this error.